# Get X Y coordinates on click after device width change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onclick, location, position

I'm making a Where is Waldo app. My problem is how to set Waldo's location to a fixed position so even after I change my windows size It would still give back the same coordinates? Or I try to apply the wrong logic here and it would be easier with a different approach. I have a div inside of which an img tag with the picture where you should find Waldo. (the img is bigger then the screen so you must scroll down if this matter)

Comment: Can you include some code with examples of what you've tried, it sounds like you just want a static location which should be achievable by just setting the waldo div to have a specific margin or setting left and top parameters in CSS

Comment: @LazyJ I don't have code for it cause i'm not there yet:) I have an img which you should find waldo in but i don't have a single waldo img

Comment: Okay I'll try and cook up an example for you, but what you want is a static position no matter the screen size right?

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you correctly you want statically sized pictures and just set a static position for waldo inside the where's waldo picture. This can be done by using `left` and `top` attributes, a small example below

```
import img from '../waldoImg1.png';
import waldo from '../waldo.webp';

export default function App() {
    return (
        <div
            id='waldoImg1'
            style={{
                backgroundImage: `url(${img})`,
                width: '1024px',
                height: '768px',
            }}
        >
            <div
                id='waldo'
                style={{
                    position: 'relative',
                    backgroundImage: `url(${waldo})`,
                    backgroundSize: 'contain',
                    width: '25px',
                    height: '50px',
                    left: '200px',
                    top: '100px',
                }}
            ></div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

This will then set the position 200 pixels from the left side and 100 pixels from the top. The styling has just been done inline for simplicity of my answer.